# How to show image in GridView form database linq

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, image, linq, gridview

i have a table with field named PIMAGE And i can't show this field.
gridview named:dgw-
my problem is that the gridview do not show the image
my code:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StorDataContext stor = new StorDataContext();

        var res = (from r in stor.Products
                   where r.PID!=13
                   select new {
                       name=r.PName,date=System.DateTime.Now.ToString(),company=r.Company,price=r.Price,quantity=r.Quantity,color=r.Color,size=r.Size,weight=r.PWeight,
                       PImage = r.PID});

        GridView1.Visible = true;
        GridView1.DataSource = res.ToList();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

and may ashx

```
public class ShowImg : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Int32 pid;
        if (context.Request.QueryString["getID"] != null)
        {
            pid = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["getID"]);
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            Stream strm = GetImage(pid);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
            while (byteSeq > 0)
            {
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
                byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
            }
        }
    }
        public Stream GetImage(int pid)
    {

        StorDataContext stor = new StorDataContext();    
        System.Data.Linq.Binary b = null;
        byte[] ibyte = null;


        Product product1 = stor.Products.First(p => p.PID == pid);

        b = product1.PImage;
        ibyte = b.ToArray();

        return new MemoryStream((byte[])ibyte);
    }
```

and aspx

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PImage">

                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/ShowImg.ashx?id=" + Eval("PImage")  %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>
```

what's wrong?
 use asp.net - sql server - linq

Comment: more info may help here. Whats your Person class look like? Whats the field you are binding to? Whats your GridView code look like?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean you have an image field in the database.
There's lots of examples available on the net for this, here's one from the [asp.net forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1564888.aspx?how%20to%20display%20image%20datatype%20in%20gridview%20or%20any%20control)

> The short version is, you would set the  control
>   within the gridview to display the image.  On the ImageField, you
>   would use the DataImageUrlField attribute to reference the name of the
>   field in the database that contains the binary image data.  Also on
>   the ImageField, use the DataImageUrlFormatString to define a path
>   that, for example, points to an ASPX handler page and passes to it the
>   specific ID value from the DataImageUrlField.
>
> The relevant line of code might look like this:
>
> <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="MyImageID"
>   DataImageUrlFormatString="MyHandlerPage.aspx?theImageID={0}" /> A
>   complete example that uses this approach and shows you the code for
>   the handler page is at:
>
> http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/207_Displaying_Images_from_Database_in_GridView.aspx

or check out [this one](http://codedisplay.com/display-images-in-gridview-from-sql-server-database-table-using-asp-net-c-vb-net/)

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "Select [Content] from Images where ID =@ID";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    SqlParameter ImageID = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.BigInt);
    ImageID.Value = context.Request.QueryString["ID"];
    cmd.Parameters.Add(ImageID);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dReader.Read();
    context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dReader["Content"]);
    dReader.Close();
    conn.Close();
}
```

and the aspx code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVImages" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HeaderStyle-BackColor="CornflowerBlue" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" CellPadding="5">
        <Columns>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="200px" 
                   ImageUrl='<%# "ImageHandler.ashx?ID=" + Eval("ID")%>'/>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>        
        </asp:GridView>
```

and your page_load in aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        using (conn)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Images", conn);
            ad.Fill(dt);
        }
        GVImages.DataSource = dt;
        GVImages.DataBind();
    }
}
```

and finally your web.config

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TESTDB;Trusted_Connection=yes;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <!--<add name="BONConnection" connectionString="Data Source=XXX.com;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;User Id=UserName;Password=YourPassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
  </connectionStrings>
...................
...................
```

Comment: i use linq query and my problem is showing image that saved in may table

Comment: that doesn't tell me anything specific? Your LINQ query is simply selecting a Person object, I dont know what the Person class looks like?

Comment: person is a class have many field and i want show field PIMAGE that field have binary image

Comment: What I posted above should work. Basically you need a custom handler that your field in your gridview is going to request - it will be requesting it as yoursite/imagehandler.ashx?id=someRecordId, which will in turn grab the image and then stream it back AS AN IMAGE (ie it does a binary write - although the code above doesn't set the content type which may be preferable).

Comment: can you provide more info? what about the above doesn't work for you? Have you tried to see if the request is coming across with the tool Fiddler? Ensure that each row is actually requesting an image from the server from a URL that you expect to be answered by the handler code.